# Implementing security in hadoop

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-sentry

I'm trying to implement security on my hadoop data.I'm using cloudera hadoop

Below are the two specific things I'm looking for

**1. Role based authorization and authentication**

**2. Encryption on data residing in HDFS**

I have looked into Kerboroes but it doesn't provide encryption for data already residing in HDFS.

Are there any other security tools i can go for? has anyone done above two security features in cloudera hadoop.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I think Apache Sentry will be best for you.You can find more information [here.](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh/sentry.html)